# SQL Queries not fetching records often while using SQL developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently tried my hand at SQL. There was a query requirement where I had to list "9.  Display the empno, ename, job, hiredate, exp of all the Mgrs". I typed

```
select EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,HIREDATE,(sysdate-hiredate)as Experience
from emp
where JOB ='Manager';
```

The result, no records fetched. Only the metadata gets displayed.

Previously the other queries are working fine.

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean, 'metadata'?

Comment: Oracle is case-sensitive, did you try `where JOB ='MANAGER'`? What do you get when you rung `select job, count(*) from emp group by job` (edit your question. Do **not** post sample data in comments)

Comment: SQL Developer does show the column names in the 'Query results' window if you 'Run statement', which I guess is the 'metadata' you refer to? It also says 'all rows fetched: 0 in x seconds'. Are you sure you're looking for a job of 'MANAGER', rather than an employee whose ID appears as the `manager_id` of another employee, for example? Depends on the table structure of course, as this isn't the sample HR schema...

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't appear to be a SQL Developer issue.  The problem appears to be that your query returns 0 rows.

String comparisons in Oracle (barring cases where you've adjusted your session's NLS settings) are case sensitive.  There are, realistically, no rows where the `job` is "Manager".  There are, realistically, rows where the `job` is "MANAGER".  You'd need to search for the string with the proper case

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp
 WHERE job = 'MANAGER'
```